# best way to implement twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

1) I have found the Twitter rush sample code from this link [Twitter with OAuth](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/)
for the integration.

I have added consumer key and secret key. But it never authorizes the app.

2) And if I use share kit it gives the error that there was a problem requesting access from twitter.
                                                                                                                                       3) If I use social framework then it will give alert if user hasn't added his/her account in settings.

I need that user shouldn't go outside the app for twitter login.

Does anyone have any idea on what would be the best way to integrate with twitter?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Hope This will help you . . .

1.Add following classes to your project 
GTMOAuthAuthentication.h/m
GTMOAuthSignIn.h/m
GTMHTTPFetcher.h/m
GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch.h/m
GTMOAuthViewTouch.xib

2 . Add following frameworks
Security.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework.

3 .set  -ObjC build option for the application target's "Other Linker Flags".

4 . Then it's time for some coding .

import GTMOAuthAuthentication.h and GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch.h

```
- (void)signInWithTwitter
{
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
NSString *scope = @"http://api.twitter.com/";

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self authForTwitter];

[auth setCallback:@"http://www.noop.com/OAuthCallback"];

GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;

viewController = [[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                             language:nil
                                                      requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                    authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                       accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                       authentication:auth
                                                       appServiceName:@"AppName : Twitter"
                                                             delegate:self
finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}

- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)authForTwitter {
GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
            consumerKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY
             privateKey:TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET];

[auth setServiceProvider:@"Twitter"];

return auth;
}

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error {

    if(error)
    {
         //handle error
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff as per your app.
    }
}
```

NOte : if you get error message like "failed to validate oauth signature and token" then check you system time is correct or not .

Comment: I have successfully login with the twitter authentication. Really thanks alot. But what would be the method to post the image and link to twitter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that user shouldn't go outside you can use  **ACAccountStore** `Account.Framework` and `Social.framework` for iOS 6,

```
 NSUrl *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"];
  NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:twittername,@"screen_name",nil];

     account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    NSArray *twitterAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

    // Runing on iOS 6
    if (NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") && [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:NULL completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted)
             {

                 SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url                                      parameters:params];

                 [request setAccount:[twitterAccounts lastObject]];

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                {

                                    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request.preparedURLRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response1, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                                     {
                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                                        {
                                                            if (data)
                                                            {
//                                                                [self loadData:data];

                                                                NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                                NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;


                                                                NSLog(@"data:%@",newStr);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                     }];
                                });
             }
         }];
    }
    else if (NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController") && [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) // Runing on iOS 5
    {
        [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted)
             {
                 TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:params requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
                 [request setAccount:[twitterAccounts lastObject]];

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                {
                                    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request.signedURLRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response1, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                                     {
                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                                        {                             
                                                            if (data)                                 
                                                            {                                 
                                                                NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                                                                NSLog(@"data:%@",newStr);                                                           }
                                                        });
                                     }];


                                });
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

You have to retain **ACAccountStore**: in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ACAccountStore *account;
```